# Comparing cursor icon bitmaps in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, bitmap

I want to check whether the cursor icon has changed by comparing the bitmaps.

So far I have tried the snippet below, but it does not work properly.

```py
import win32api, win32con, win32gui, win32ui

info = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 35, 35)
hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

hdc.DrawIcon((0,0), info[1])
hbmp.SaveBitmapFile(hdc, 'icon.bmp')
```

This code just produces a black rectangle bitmap (found most of it on the internet). In general I would rather not save the bitmap and just compare the 2 bitmaps as images with pillow, but i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have created the memory DC and the memory bitmap, `SelectObject` is used to select the memory bitmap into the memory DC. Only in this way can the bitmap work.

Modified code：

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui, win32ui

info = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 35, 35)
hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)

hdc.DrawIcon((0,0), info[1])
hbmp.SaveBitmapFile(hdc, 'icon.bmp')

win32gui.DestroyIcon(info[1])
win32gui.DeleteObject(hbmp.GetHandle())
hdc.DeleteDC()
```

When you no longer need the bitmap, call the `DeleteObject` function to delete it.

Similar operations apply to cursor and memory DC release.